# How does plm() function in R and panelOLS() in Python handle missing values

Tags: python, r, panel-data, plm

I am building a model, using function `plm()` from the `plm` package.

One of my x variables contains `NA`s because I used a t-1 lag calculations.

My R code looks like this

```
panel_df <- pdata.frame(df, index = c("AUTHOR_ID", "Year"), drop.index = TRUE, row.names = TRUE)

plmFit1 <- plm(y~ x1 + x2 + x3_t_1, data = panel_df, effect = 'twoways')
```

The best thing I found out in [documentation online](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plm/plm.pdf) is

*The data are not necessarily made consecutive (regular time series with distance 1), because balancedness does not imply consecutiveness. For making the data consecutive, use make.pconsecutive() (and, optionally, set argument balanced = TRUE to make consecutive and balanced, see also Examples for a comparison of the two functions. Note: Rows of (p)data.frames (elements for pseries) with NA values in individual or time index are not examined but silently dropped before the data are made balanced. In this case, it cannot be inferred which individual or time period is meant by the missing value(s) (see also Examples). Especially, this means: NA values in the first/last position of the original time periods for an individual are dropped, which are usually meant to depict the beginning and ending of the time series for that individual. Thus, one might want to check if there are any NA values in the index variables before applying make.pbalanced, and especially check for NA values in the first and last position for each individual in original data and, if so, maybe set those to some meaningful begin/end value for the time series.*

I also did not find anything for [panelOLS](https://bashtage.github.io/linearmodels/panel/panel/linearmodels.panel.model.PanelOLS.html).

How do they handle missing values by default, because I receive output with coefficients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot comment on Python's `panelOLS` but would assume it is similar.

`plm` follows standard `lm` behaviour: drop observations (lines) with `NA` value prior to estimation. The documentation you cite is not related to this behaviour.

Compare your data pre estimation (`df`, `panel_df`) and data post estimation (as found the in the model object in `$model`).

You can also look at `?na.omit` and read the described behaviour for `na.omit` (other approaches described there are not supported by `plm`).

Here is an example:

```
library(plm)
data(Grunfeld) 
pdf <- pdata.frame(Grunfeld)

head(pdf)
#>        firm year   inv  value capital
#> 1-1935    1 1935 317.6 3078.5     2.8
#> 1-1936    1 1936 391.8 4661.7    52.6
#> 1-1937    1 1937 410.6 5387.1   156.9
#> 1-1938    1 1938 257.7 2792.2   209.2
#> 1-1939    1 1939 330.8 4313.2   203.4
#> 1-1940    1 1940 461.2 4643.9   207.2

pdf[3, "inv"] <- NA # set one value to NA in 3rd row (1-1937)
head(pdf)
#>        firm year   inv  value capital
#> 1-1935    1 1935 317.6 3078.5     2.8
#> 1-1936    1 1936 391.8 4661.7    52.6
#> 1-1937    1 1937    NA 5387.1   156.9
#> 1-1938    1 1938 257.7 2792.2   209.2
#> 1-1939    1 1939 330.8 4313.2   203.4
#> 1-1940    1 1940 461.2 4643.9   207.2

nrow(pdf) # 200
#> [1] 200

# estimate model    
mod <- plm(inv ~ value + capital, data = pdf, model = "within")

head(mod$model) # no entry for 1-1937
#>          inv  value capital
#> 1-1935 317.6 3078.5     2.8
#> 1-1936 391.8 4661.7    52.6
#> 1-1938 257.7 2792.2   209.2
#> 1-1939 330.8 4313.2   203.4
#> 1-1940 461.2 4643.9   207.2
#> 1-1941 512.0 4551.2   255.2

nrow(mod$model) # 199 rows
#> [1] 199
```